# libcurl rtsp keep alive with rtsp server

Tags: rtsp, keep-alive

I was implementing rtsp with libcurl(sample code https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html) 
I received RTP data after sending PLAY option.
But the connection broke about ten minutes.
I thought it might send heartbeat message to rtsp sever to keep session alive.

How to keep connection alive with libcurl ?

Code Flow :

```
// Set Option

// Set Describe

// Set Setup

// PLAY

/* Receive RTP DATA*/

while(1)

{

curl_easy_set_opt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, rtsp_write);

curl_easy_set_opt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, NULL);

.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send CURL_RTSPREQ_OPTIONS again. I send it every 30 seconds.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

The RTSP connection indeed requires the heartbeat. It is specified in **RCF 2326**, *section 12.37* and **ONVIF streaming specification**, *section 5.2.1.1.1*.

Basically you do:

1. Optionally set the timeout parameter (in seconds), the usual default is 60sec.
2. The RTSP `SETUP` response should contain timeout and client should use it to keep-alive the connection.
3. Client should call the RTSP server using any RTSP method or send RTCP RR. The recommended meethod is to send RTSP `SET_PARAMETER` request.